# MacBook doesn't find any Bluetooth device

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

After running `sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior=always` because I wanted macOS to use only external Bluetooth dongles instead of the internal one I cannot find any Bluetooth devices anymore when the external dongle is not connected. I already ran 
`sudo nvram -d bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior`
 to reset the setting, restarted macOS several times, reset the NVRAM, reset the Bluetooth module, etc..

Is there anything I missed after using these Bluetooth devices with my external dongle? When now plugging in the external dongle again, it finds all the devices properly.

I tried to search for the devices with my iPad (Magic Keyboard 2), and it instantly recognizes it.

Edit: I just erased my macOS installation and reinstalled High Sierra, but the problem persists.

Edit2:

The system report is showing me that seemingly there are devices connected (when the internal device is active) although I removed all devices via the menu bar option. Is there maybe a correlation? Is there an option to manually remove the bluetooth connections?

```
Devices (Paired, Configured, etc.):

24-1b-7a-21-aa-da:
Address:    24-1B-7A-21-AA-DA
Major Type: Miscellaneous
Minor Type: Unknown
Services:   
Paired: No
Configured: Yes
Connected:  No
Class of Device:    0x00 0x00 0x0000

ac-e4-b5-c9-98-6b:
Address:    AC-E4-B5-C9-98-6B
Major Type: Miscellaneous
Minor Type: Unknown
Services:   
Paired: No
Configured: Yes
Connected:  No
Class of Device:    0x00 0x00 0x0000

78-fd-94-5e-f6-a6:
Address:    78-FD-94-5E-F6-A6
Major Type: Miscellaneous
Minor Type: Unknown
Services:   
Paired: No
Configured: Yes
Connected:  No
Class of Device:    0x00 0x00 0x0000

dc-9b-9c-ca-a4-e0:
Address:    DC-9B-9C-CA-A4-E0
Major Type: Miscellaneous
Minor Type: Unknown
Services:   
Paired: No
Configured: Yes
Connected:  No
Class of Device:    0x00 0x00 0x0000
```

Comment: did you factory reset all Apple-BT devices

Comment: Yeah I did that. I connected the devices to my dongle, then clicked on the Bluetooth symbol in the menu bar while pressing option + shift, and then ‘Debug -> Factory Reset all Apple devices’. It did work, but I still can’t find them via my internal Bluetooth, when the dongle is not connected..

Comment: Download Additional Tools for Xcode 10.1 from Apple at `https://developer.apple.com/download/more/`  then use the Bluetooth explorer to investigate (you will need a account, it  is free)

Comment: I did download it, but unfortunately it does not start. Also tried older versions, but no one worked.

Comment: it works on High Sierra.. open the .dmg >Hardware Folder >then BT explorer

Comment: I am on Mojave. Did exactly what you describe, but nothing happens when I open it.

Comment: Just completely wiped Mojave and installed a clean High Sierra, but the problem persists and Bluetooth Explorer does still not start up.. Do you have anything additional installed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after inserting an external bluetooth dongle my Macbook pro 2018 internal bluetooth control has gone, tried everything, resetting SMC, NVRAM, installing a bran new Mojave on an USB disk
I opened a ticket to Apple and after a morning of retries they concluded my internal controller hardware is broken.

**I suggest you to run "Bluetooth Explorer"** (I was able but "Bluetooth Explorer" does not detect my internal controller..)

Comment: How can I run Bluetooth Explorer?